# Show in multi currency values in lwc data table

Tags: lightning-web-components, multi-currency

Is there any workaround to show org currency and user currency in lwc data table
as shown on the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should [Enable Multiple Currencies](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_enable_multicurrency.htm&type=5) on your org.

Assume we have some currency `Price__c` field on `Contact` and our Apex Controller would look the next basic way:

```java
public with sharing class MultiCurrencyController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Contact getTestRecord() {
        return [
                SELECT
                        Price__c,
                        convertCurrency(Price__c) ConvertedPrice__c
                FROM Contact
                WHERE LastName = 'TestC'
        ][0];
    }
}
```

We used [convertCurrency()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_querying_currency_fields.htm) SOQL/SOSL function to convert currency `Price__c` field to the user's currency and [Alias Notation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_alias.htm) to be able getting both converted and original prices separately.

Then our LWC would look:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getTestRecord from '@salesforce/apex/MultiCurrencyController.getTestRecord';
import CURRENCY from '@salesforce/i18n/currency';

export default class MultiCurrency extends LightningElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        getTestRecord()
            .then((result) => {
                const desiredString = `USD ${result.Price__c} (${CURRENCY} ${result.ConvertedPrice__c})`;
                console.log(desiredString);/* USD 10.00 (INR 716.90) depending on the current user Currency */
            });
    }

}
```

To access the currency code or any other internationalization properties from LWC you should import them from the [`@salesforce/i18n`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_i18n) scoped module.

Answer (score 0):

The `format` method in a SOQL query can help you achieve this. Have your `@AuraEnabled` method use the `format` method along with an alias:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<My_Object__c> getRecords() {
  return [SELECT Id, Name, format(My_Currency_Field__c) FormattedCurrency 
          FROM My_Object__c];
}
```

The alias for the field is not necessary, but apparently required for this use case. When I tested this, `format(My_Currency_Field__c)` resulted in the LWC getting back the single-currency numeric value. I had to alias the field (`format(My_Currency_Field__c) FormattedCurrency`) to make sure the formatted string is returned to the LWC.

In the LWC column configuration, get rid of `type : 'currency'` on the column configuration because you don't have a numeric currency anymore but a formatted string.